# What theorem tells us that a bound on all partial sums implies a bound on the infinite series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I see the following fact used in published proofs without citing any theorem.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq B \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \implies
\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i \leq B
$$

It seems intuitively true, but real analysis is so often counterintuitive...

Comment: The sum is the limit of those partial sums so it's no bigger than $B$. What more do you need for a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the sum of an infinite series is the limit of the partial sums of the series. Therefore many statements about the sum of a series are obtained from the corresponding statements about limits of sequences.

In this case the relevant fact about sequences is the following: if $\{s_n\}$ is a sequence such that $s_n\leq B$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=s$, then $s\leq B$. Indeed, if $s>B$ then there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $s>B-\varepsilon$, and by choosing $N$ large enough that $|s_n-s|<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N$ we get $s_N>B$, a contradiction.

Taking $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ and $s=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i$ then proves the claim in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer says, it follows from the fact that the infinite sum is in fact *defined* as the limit of its partial sums. However, another way to see this is that if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i >B$, then at some point, the sequence
$$ x_1\quad,\quad x_1+x_2\quad,\quad x_1+x_2+x_3\quad,\quad\dotsc $$
must be greater than $B$. But then we get a partial sum that is greater than $B$ - a contradiction.

Another related point is that if all partial sums are strictly smaller than $B$, the infinite sum need not be: Just consider $\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-i}=1$.